# Android SeekBar issues

Tags: android, seekbar

First, I am trying to create SeekBar with a change listener. I hope I am doing this correctly. Below, red is giving me a null exception. I believe that is because my list is one xml and my seekbar/textview layout is another xml. Is that the case? How would I go about grabbing it?

seekbars.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/seekBarLayout"
>
     <TextView
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:background="#aa0000"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:id="@+id/seekBarLabel"/> 

      <TextView
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:background="#aa0000"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:id="@+id/seekBarValue"/>


     <SeekBar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/seekBarID"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

seekbarlist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView

        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

android code

```
package thisPackage.Tabs;



public class ColorsActivity extends ListActivity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

//Array Adapter that will hold our ArrayList and display the items on the ListView
SeekBarAdaptor seekBarAdaptor;

//List that will  host our items and allow us to modify that array adapter
ArrayList<SeekBar> seekBarArrayList=null;
TextView myValueText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.seekbarlist);

    //Initialize ListView        
    ListView lstTest= getListView();

     //Initialize our ArrayList
    seekBarArrayList = new ArrayList<SeekBar>();

    //Initialize our array adapter 
    seekBarAdaptor = new SeekBarAdaptor(ColorsActivity.this, R.layout.seekbars,seekBarArrayList);
    //setContentView(R.layout.seekbars);
    SeekBar red = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBarID);
    red.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
   // SeekBar blue = new SeekBar(this);

    //Set the above adapter as the adapter of choice for our list
    lstTest.setAdapter(seekBarAdaptor);

    seekBarArrayList.add(red);
    //seekBarArrayList.add(blue);
}
 public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {
     //myLayout = (LinearLayout)seekBar.findViewById(R.id.seekBarLayout);
     myValueText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seekBarValue);  
     myValueText.setText("hello");
    //myValueText.setText("text");
 }
 public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){

 }
 public void onStartTrackingTouch (SeekBar seekBar){
 }

}
```

logcat

03-15 00:01:52.020: D/AndroidRuntime(345): Shutting down VM

03-15 00:01:52.020: W/dalvikvm(345): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)

03-15 00:01:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(345): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-15 00:01:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(345): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{thisPackage.Tabs/thisPackage.Tabs.ColorsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

03-15 00:01:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)

03-15 00:01:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1487)

03-15 00:01:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)

03-15 00:01:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)

03-15 00:01:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:654)

03-15 00:01:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:326)

03-15 00:01:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:132)

03-15 00:01:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:456)

03-15 00:01:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)

03-15 00:01:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)

03-15 00:01:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)

03-15 00:01:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

03-15 00:01:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

03-15 00:01:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)

03-15 00:01:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

03-15 00:01:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

03-15 00:01:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)

03-15 00:01:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)

03-15 00:01:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

03-15 00:01:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(345): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

03-15 00:01:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at thisPackage.Tabs.ColorsActivity.onCreate(ColorsActivity.java:52)

03-15 00:01:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

03-15 00:01:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)

03-15 00:01:52.040: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  ... 18 more

Comment: Null pointer exception occurs when null value is accessed. So check that the red value is not null. please post logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is R.id.seekBarID refers to something in R.layout.seekbarlist? If not, then

```
SeekBar red = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBarID);
```

will returns null as it cannot find the specified view, it would be helpful if you can post the 2 layout files as well.

Comment: Yes. This is what I assumed. I appended the XML files.

Comment: You haven't include seekbars.xml into seekbarlist.xml, and haven't done so in your code either, since you called setContentView(R.layout.seekbarlist); this means that _nothing_ from seekbars.xml has been added to the content. You should add <include android:id="@+id/seekBarLayout" layout="@layout/seekbars" />  to the appropriate place (defined by where do you want it shown) in your seekbarlist.xml